# Is there a law regarding visiting one's job site on days off?

Tags: california, personal-questions

I work at a bar and the General Manager told us no one is allowed to come to the bar on their day off and we can only drink coke while working. Is there law regarding that?

Comment: This is hardly a matter of employment law. If the manager doesn't want you there on your off days, and you want to keep the job, don't be there.

Comment: What will you do with an answer? Will you go there on your day off? Will you drink Pepsi? Will you sue them? I don't see any positive outcome and really don't see a point in asking the question.

Comment: I don't see any law regarding that. I think it is just a matter of the GM's want to implement a good policy out of their own precaution. And, they do have many good reasons to implement that policy as you can already see.

Comment: Drinking while serving customers in many states is illegal, if it’s illegal in CA, should be something you research yourself.  However, your boss is within their right, to not allow you to drink and serve customers.  They are also allowed to NOT serve you alcohol on your day off. If you disagree with the policy, quit, but they can still decide to refuse to serve you

Comment: Moral: Don't get a job in the bar you want to drink in. You usually can't do so while on duty, and usually can't do so off duty either. Find another bar to work in, or to drink in, assuming you want to do both.

Comment: Does the GM allow you to drink other non-alcoholic drinks or water?

Comment: @hunger - Preventing the employee from drinking water, while working would be illegal, I seriously doubt anyone is preventing the author from drinking any liquids. Limits on where they physically can drink water, while at work, might be something that exist but I doubt it.

Comment: @Donald
Of course that would be illegal, but many things in this Q&A revolve around things being legal or not.
When first reading the question, I honestly wondered if they were only allowed to drink coke exclusively, which would be very unhealthy. It then came to my mind that it shouldn't be understood in a literal sense, but the question could be made much clearer in that sense.
There's a vast difference between not allowing alcoholic drinks (which seems reasonable to me) and only allowing coke (which does not).

Answer (score 18):

This is normal for many bars. Staff should not be drinking/socialising outside their working at their place of employment for many good reasons. The exception is usually when the hierarchy invites you to do so.

While working if the GM only wants you drinking coke, that's up to them. Obviously you should not be drinking alcohol while actually working whether it's in a bar or almost anywhere else.

Answer (score 11):

Not being allowed to drink alcohol on the job (or arrive drunk) is the default for pretty much *any* job.

Not being allowed on the premises outside designated working hours is actually pretty normal for jobs that don't involve customer service.

The fact that your manager said "only Coke" is probably because that is their colloquialism for "no alcohol", or maybe it is what they give you for free. They are allowed to offer you anything they like for free. They are also allowed to restrict what you drink in front of customers, for example it would look bad if you drank Pepsi and worked for a Coke shop.

But you are allowed to drink anything non-alcoholic you want, privately in a rest room, as long as you bring it, or the business allows you to purchase it there.

So the only real difference here is that the manager does not want staff to mingle with customers on their day off. That's their decision to make, you can go to any other bar you like. Everything else is already standard for any job you will take in your life.

Comment: "you are allowed to drink whatever you want, privately in a rest room, as long as you bring it, or the business allows you to purchase it there." - You might want to clarify that by anything you mean non-alcoholic beverages.

Comment: @Donald Thanks, good call.

Comment: And the GM mentioning "coke" means the bar's coke, not stuff you brought yourself. You can drink anything non-alcoholic if you brought it yourself, unless the venue is licensed to serve a specific brand, then be smart about it (Pepsi/Coke, etc)

Answer (score 8):

I can answer for our (Australian) laws.  Any person working on a private premises can ask someone not to be there, if they refuse that person would be trespassing.

Simple as that.

On an interesting but somewhat related anecdote the gym I go to doesn't allow their workers to go to any other gym on their days off.  Is it legal? Probably not.  Do they do it anyway? Yep.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there law regarding that?

There is no law. Of course you could be fired.

Comment: Well, there are trespassing laws. If you're told to get off private property, generally or at specific times, you get off unless you want to risk dealing with courts and possibly police. It's civil law rather than criminal law, but it is law, and barring evidence of discrimination against protected classes it really is the host's decision. Speaking as a woodworker, "don't fret, just cope."

Comment: My point is that if the owner orders someone off the property, for any nondiscriminatory reason, the police *could* get involved if the individual refuses. Civil, not criminal, and not tied specifically to employment or drinking, but it's still a law.